Can we say convergence of norms implies convergence of sequences?
Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $T \in B(X)$ is an operator with $\|T\|<1$ then $I-T$ is invertible and the inverse is given by
$$
(I-T)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n .
$$
Proof
Because $X$ is a Banach space, so is $B(X)$ by Theorem 4.27. Since $\|T\|<1$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|T\|^n$ converges and hence, as $\left\|T^n\right\| \leq\|T\|^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\|T^n\right\|$ also converges. Therefore $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n$ converges by Theorem 2.30. Let $S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n$ and let $S_k=\sum_{n=0}^k T^n$. Then the sequence $\left\{S_k\right\}$ converges to $S$ in $B(X)$. Now
$$
\left\|(I-T) S_k-I\right\|=\left\|I-T^{k+1}-I\right\|=\left\|-T^{k+1}\right\| \leq\|T\|^{k+1} .
$$
Since $\|T\|<1$ we deduce that $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}(I-T) S_k=I$. Therefore,
$$
(I-T) S=(I-T) \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} S_k=\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}(I-T) S_k=I,
$$
by Lemma 4.32. Similarly, $S(I-T)=I$ so $I-T$ is invertible and $(I-T)^{-1}=S$.
Question: why Since $\|T\|<1$ we deduce that $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}(I-T) S_k=I$? I know since $\|T\|<1$, we can get $\|(I-T) S_k-I\| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.But do we have  convergence of norms implies convergence of sequences?

This is the definition of convergence. In any normed space, we say a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x\in X$ if $||x_n-x||\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

By definition, a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in a Banach space (or even a normed space) $X$ converges to $x$ in $X$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$, you have that $\|x_{n} - x\| < \varepsilon$. This is equivalent to saying that the sequence of real numbers $(\|x_{n} - x\|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to the real number $0$.
For your case, the observation that $\|T\| < 1$ implies that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \|T\|^{k+1} = 0$. Because of the inequality $\|(I-T)S_{k} - I\| \leq \|T\|^{k+1}$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \|(I-T)S_{k} - I\| = 0$ by the squeeze theorem and the sequence $((I-T)S_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $I$ in $B(X)$. This is the same as saying that $\lim_{k\to\infty} (I-T)S_{k} = I$ in $B(X)$.
